# Ошибка при получении данных с БД golang

Tags: mysql, база-данных, golang

Подключился к бд правильно, теперь хотел получить данные с таблицы. Но появилась ошибка в panic(err)
код:

```
type Test struct {
  Word string
  Part string
  CategoryId uint16
  Transcript, Translation, ExampleEng, ExampleRu, Highlight string
  MisOne string
  MisTwo string
  MisThree string
}
//подключение к бд, данные показывать не могу
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "login:password@tcp(host:port)/db_name")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer db.Close()
res, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM `dictionary`")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  for res.Next(){
    var test Test
    err = res.Scan(&test.CategoryId, &test.Word, &test.Transcript, &test.Translation, &test.ExampleEng, &test.ExampleRu, &test.Highlight, &test.Part)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, test.Word)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, test.Part)
  }
```

ошибка:

```
    2021/02/15 17:13:47 http: panic serving [::1]:64934: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 4 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00007aaa0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc0000c8140)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e0e0, 0xc00009a000)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e0e0, 0xc00009a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e0e0, 0xc00009a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e0e0, 0xc00009a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00007aaa0, 0x133ef60, 0xc000092000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:47 http: panic serving [::1]:64935: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 5 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00007ab40)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc0000c8320)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e2a0, 0xc0001c8000)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e2a0, 0xc0001c8000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e2a0, 0xc0001c8000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00009e2a0, 0xc0001c8000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00007ab40, 0x133ef60, 0xc00018e2c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:47 http: panic serving [::1]:64940: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00011e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc0000c8460)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a0e0, 0xc000126000)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a0e0, 0xc000126000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a0e0, 0xc000126000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a0e0, 0xc000126000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00011e000, 0x133ef60, 0xc000110040)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:48 http: panic serving [::1]:64949: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 66 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000248000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00020e1e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e0e0, 0xc00024a000)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e0e0, 0xc00024a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e0e0, 0xc00024a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e0e0, 0xc00024a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000248000, 0x133ef60, 0xc000222040)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:48 http: panic serving [::1]:64950: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 52 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0000ec000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00020e230)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a2a0, 0xc00009a100)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a2a0, 0xc00009a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a2a0, 0xc00009a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00012a2a0, 0xc00009a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0000ec000, 0x133ef60, 0xc000092500)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:48 http: panic serving [::1]:64955: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 73 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0002480a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc000148460)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e2a0, 0xc00024a100)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e2a0, 0xc00024a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e2a0, 0xc00024a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e2a0, 0xc00024a100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002480a0, 0x133ef60, 0xc000222280)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:53 http: panic serving [::1]:64978: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 78 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000248140)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00005c3c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b41c0, 0xc0001c8100)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b41c0, 0xc0001c8100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b41c0, 0xc0001c8100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b41c0, 0xc0001c8100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000248140, 0x133ef60, 0xc00018e380)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:53 http: panic serving [::1]:64979: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 79 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0002481e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00020e460)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e460, 0xc00024a200)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e460, 0xc00024a200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e460, 0xc00024a200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e460, 0xc00024a200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002481e0, 0x133ef60, 0xc000222480)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:13:53 http: panic serving [::1]:64984: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 12 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00007abe0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00020e640)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b4380, 0xc0001c8200)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b4380, 0xc0001c8200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b4380, 0xc0001c8200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc0001b4380, 0xc0001c8200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00007abe0, 0x133ef60, 0xc00018e5c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:14:24 http: panic serving [::1]:65108: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 91 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00011e0a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc00020e7d0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e620, 0xc000126200)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e620, 0xc000126200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e620, 0xc000126200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e620, 0xc000126200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00011e0a0, 0x133ef60, 0xc0001105c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:14:24 http: panic serving [::1]:65109: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 108 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000248280)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc0000c8550)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e7e0, 0xc00024a300)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e7e0, 0xc00024a300)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e7e0, 0xc00024a300)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e7e0, 0xc00024a300)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000248280, 0x133ef60, 0xc000222780)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
2021/02/15 17:14:24 http: panic serving [::1]:65114: dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
goroutine 121 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000248320)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x12a9f40, 0xc000148690)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.words(0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e9a0, 0xc00024a400)
    /Users/user/Desktop/Educ/main.go:35 +0x385
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12fa928, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e9a0, 0xc00024a400)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14c0ca0, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e9a0, 0xc00024a400)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001b4000, 0x133e9a0, 0xc00024e9a0, 0xc00024a400)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000248320, 0x133ef60, 0xc000222b80)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
```

Comment: *connect: connection refused* мало похоже на "Подключился к бд правильно"

Comment: поддерживаю выше. клиент не подключен

Comment: при panic(err) наверняка любая ошибка, даже не критическая, вызывает падение приложения, причем здесь даже мы не видим в какой строчке кода упало

Comment: @Akina эта ошибка появляется по панике после "SELECT * FROM `dictionary`"

Comment: *connection refused* означает "в соединении отказано". Вы можете выполнить хоть какой-то запрос в своей базе, к которой Вы "подключились правильно" без указанной ошибки? например, `SELECT VERSION();` или просто `SELECT 123;`?

Comment: @Akina добавил код подключения к бд. Может дело в том что я запускаю все это на localhost? Я также пробовал поставить в ListenAndServe порт хостинга, но тогда не загружалось вовсе

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить строку подключение на

`sql.Open("mysql", "login:password@(host:port)/db_name?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local")`